# How to join all keys correctly / How to identify join keys

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so I'm having problems with creating tables, join, or at least I thought, when joining multiple tables resulting in duplicate result.

I have one big table which contains all the data. Also, I have Multiple sub-table(partitioned table) that was created from the big table and contains some information of the big table. I want the query which extract from the sub-tables to have the same result.

This is my query of how I created the 3 sub-tables.
first table - traffic

```
 create table `traffic` as

select 
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
userId,
max(case when c.index = 10 then c.value else null end) as universal_id,
max(case when c.index = 8 then c.value else null end) as ps_project_id,
max(case when c.index = 39 then c.value else null end) as ps_campaign_id,
visitStartTime,
date,
visitNumber,
adContent,
campaign,
campaignCode,
keyword,
medium,
referralPath,
source,
channelGrouping,
campaignId

from(

select 
fullVisitorId, 
visitId, 
userId, 
visitStartTime, 
date, 
visitNumber, 
trafficSource.adContent,
trafficSource.campaign,
trafficSource.campaignCode,
trafficSource.keyword,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.referralPath,
trafficSource.source,
channelGrouping,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
h.customdimensions

from `ga_sessions_*`

left join unnest (hits) as h

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20211117' and '20211117' 
)
left join unnest (customdimensions) as c

group by 
fullVisitorId, 
visitId, 
userId, 
visitStartTime, 
date, 
visitNumber, 
adContent,
campaign,
campaignCode,
keyword,
medium,
referralPath,
source,
channelGrouping,
campaignId
```

Second table - hits page

```
    create table `hits_page` as


select 
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
userId,
max(case when c.index = 10 then c.value else null end) as universal_id,
max(case when c.index = 8 then c.value else null end) as ps_project_id,
max(case when c.index = 39 then c.value else null end) as ps_campaign_id,
visitStartTime,
date,
visitNumber,
pagePath,
pagePathLevel1,
pagePathLevel2,
pagePathLevel3,
pagePathLevel4,
hostname,
pageTitle,
searchKeyword,
searchCategory

from(

select 
fullVisitorId, 
visitId, 
userId, 
visitStartTime, 
date, 
visitNumber, 
h.page.pagePath,
h.page.pagePathLevel1,
h.page.pagePathLevel2,
h.page.pagePathLevel3,
h.page.pagePathLevel4,
h.page.hostname,
h.page.pageTitle,
h.page.searchKeyword,
h.page.searchCategory,
h.customdimensions

from `ga_sessions_*`

left join unnest (hits) as h

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20211117' and '20211117' 
)
left join unnest (customdimensions) as c

group by 
fullVisitorId, 
visitId, 
userId, 
visitStartTime, 
date, 
visitNumber, 
pagePath,
pagePathLevel1,
pagePathLevel2,
pagePathLevel3,
pagePathLevel4,
hostname,
pageTitle,
searchKeyword,
searchCategory
```

The third table - hits

```
create table `hits` as

select 
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
userId,
max(case when c.index = 10 then c.value else null end) as universal_id,
max(case when c.index = 8 then c.value else null end) as ps_project_id,
max(case when c.index = 39 then c.value else null end) as ps_campaign_id,
visitStartTime,
date,
visitNumber,
type,
hitNumber,
hour,
minute,
isEntrance,
isExit,
isInteraction,
time,
referer

from(

select 
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
userId,
visitStartTime,
date,
visitNumber,
h.type,
h.hitNumber,
h.hour,
h.minute,
h.isEntrance,
h.isExit,
h.isInteraction,
h.time,
h.referer,
h.customdimensions

from `ga_sessions_*`

left join unnest (hits) as h

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20211117' and '20211117' 
)
left join unnest (customdimensions) as c

group by 
fullVisitorId, 
visitId, 
userId, 
visitStartTime, 
date, 
visitNumber, 
type,
hitNumber,
hour,
minute,
isEntrance,
isExit,
isInteraction,
time,
referer
```

Now, the query which I used is the following:

```
select 
    c.pagepath,
    a.medium,
    a.source,
    count(*) as count_pageviews
 
from `traffic` as a

 join `hits_page` as c
 on a.fullVisitorId = c.fullVisitorId 
 and a.visitId = c.visitId 
 and a.visitStartTime = c.visitStartTime 
 and a.date = c.date
 and a.visitNumber = c.visitNumber

 join `hits` as d
 on a.fullVisitorId = d.fullVisitorId 
 and a.visitId = d.visitId 
 and a.visitStartTime = d.visitStartTime 
 and a.date = d.date
 and a.visitNumber = d.visitNumber
 
where pagepath = "/sellland"
and type = "PAGE"
 
group by 1,2,3
 
order by count_pageviews desc
```

As you can see, I joined all columns which appear on 3 of these sub-table `fullVisitorId`,`visitId`,`visitStartTime`,`date`,`visitNumber` except `userId`, `pscampaignid`, `universal_Id`, `ps_project_Id` which has no data and show no result when connected. This return the following result:

```
Row pagepath        medium      source  count_pageviews 
1   /sellland        none       direct        835
2   /sellland    facebook_ad  facebook        541
3   /sellland        cpc        google        390
4   /sellland      referral  lm.facebook.com  225
```

I have made updates to how I created those 3 tables, the results look closer now. I have a feeling that it was due to how I created the table, I will focus on that now.:

```
Row pagepath        medium      source     count_pageviews  
1   /sellland      facebook_ad  facebook         388
2   /sellland         cpc        google          252
3   /sellland         none       direct          182
4   /sellland      referral  lm.facebook.com     83
```

But, it should return something like this

```
Row pagepath       medium      source      count_pageviews  
1   /sellland   facebook_ad   facebook         357
2   /sellland       cpc        google          199
3   /sellland     (none)      (direct)         110
4   /sellland     referral   lm.facebook.com    48
```

I'm having trouble finding out the wrong in this problem. I am not sure if it is because the way I `unnest` or the `join` all the columns which appear on all of these 3 tables itself or others. Thank you in advance for all your inputs.

Comment: Can you help me clarify what is `count_pageviews` in your question. why not just use `sum(c.visitNumber)` from your table `hits_page` removing the unnecesary join to `hits`. The reason is because `hits` will add as much rows as visitnumber on `hits_page` have.

Comment: @Betjens `count_pageviews` acts as like pageview count in Google Analytics, it basically count the number of pageviews for every pagepath. `visitnumber` I believe does not count the same way as pageview in Google Analytics as I am also trying to compare this number to Google Analytics as well to make sure both are correct.

Comment: I made some adjustments to the table, now the result looks closer to the big table (google analytics). Basically, the major change would be that Ichanged join to left join .

Comment: If you are comparing to an external source you should provide us with sample data (input and output) and a way to compare the results so we can help you find those points. If you can replicate the issue with the current available public data `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_********` . It will give us a better way to check your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, looks like I found an answer. I'm not sure if this is an absolute answer but it works for me so far, feel free to correct me if im wrong. So, I believe the problem here is not joining all the join keys causing the data to duplicate. I was trying to query the hits level data but did not join hit level key. Therefore, I did connect one more key which is hit.hitNumber to connect all hit level row to the surface. To anybody unfamiliar with this, I think in hit level there are arrays(data within data). It looks something like this. Each row has more than 1 data, so we need to unwrap the data to be usable. Hence, by unnesting and connecting said data with hit.hitNumber, I able to get the correct number compare to google analytics.

[image: array image]

By unnesting, it should look like this.

[image]

Here is my code that got it working:

```
select
   c.pagepath,
   a.medium,
   a.source,
   count(*) as count_pageviews
 
from `traffic` as a
 
join `hits_page as c
on a.fullVisitorId = c.fullVisitorId
and a.visitId = c.visitId
and a.visitStartTime = c.visitStartTime
and a.date = c.date
and a.visitNumber = c.visitNumber
and a.hitNumber = c.hitNumber
 
join `hits` as d
on a.fullVisitorId = d.fullVisitorId
and a.visitId = d.visitId
and a.visitStartTime = d.visitStartTime
and a.date = d.date
and a.visitNumber = d.visitNumber
and a.hitNumber = d.hitNumber
 
where  c.pagepath = "/sellland"
and d.type = "PAGE"
 
group by 1,2,3
 
order by count_pageviews desc
```

Reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/explore-arrays-and-structs-for-better-performance-in-google-bigquery-8978fb00a5bc